# Runtime Error when running a LDA model of gensim on Windows

Tags: python, program-entry-point, gensim

Okay, so i know this is a Windows error and not a Gensim error. Based on previous examples on the internet and other comments/solutions from Stack Overflow I came up with the code below. However, the code never makes it to the print of the coherence score. The details are: Windows 10, Visual Code, Python 3.8.13.

My question is any idea how to fix this or what I am doing wrong?

```
from multiprocessing import Process, freeze_support
import re
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
from gensim.models.coherencemodel import CoherenceModel
from gensim.corpora.dictionary import Dictionary

def main():
    print("start main")
    texts, _ = fetch_20newsgroups( subset='all', remove=('headers', 'footers', 'quotes'), return_X_y=True )
    tokenizer = lambda s: re.findall( '\w+', s.lower() )
    texts = [ tokenizer(t) for t in  texts ]

    # Creating some random topics
    topics = [ ['space', 'planet', 'mars', 'galaxy'],
            ['cold', 'medicine', 'doctor', 'health', 'water'],
            ['cats', 'health', 'keyboard', 'car', 'banana'],
            ['windows', 'mac', 'computer', 'operating', 'system']
            ]

    # Creating a dictionary with the vocabulary
    word2id = Dictionary( texts )

    # Coherence model
    cm = CoherenceModel(topics=topics, texts=texts, coherence='c_v', dictionary=word2id)

    coherence_per_topic = cm.get_coherence()
    print("coherence", coherence_per_topic)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()
    Process(target=main).start()
```

Comment: Can you add the full error text you're seeing to your question? It's hard to identify the possible sources of an error without the error message!

Comment: There is no error it just loop 8 eight times and then 'stalls'. Had it run for 4 hours once and still was on the line with "coherence_per_topic = cm.get_coherence()"